# For authblk package, how to correctly separate authors?

Tags: authblk

**Update**: Problem solved.  See my own answer below. Credit to Werner.

I am using `authblk package` for an article.  The authors can not be separated correctly.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}    
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{1} 
\title{\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{The Title Here\\}\vspace{1ex}} 

    \author[1]{Author One}
    \author[2]{Author Two}
    \author[1,2]{Author Three} 
    \author[3]{Author Four}

    \affil[1]{\small University of California;} 
    \affil[2]{University of Missouri;} 
    \affil[3]{University of Maine} 
    \renewcommand\Authsep{, }
    \renewcommand\Authands{, and }

\date{}

\end{multicols}

\twocolumn[ 
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{fancy} 
        \begin{abstract}
         {\fontfamily{pnc}\selectfont 

         \textbf{Abstract:} Following the first case series of Hodgkin lymphomas  
}
    \end{abstract}
]


\section{Introduction}

Although Pathology is as ancient as 17th century BC Egyptian medicine, Hematopathology can only be historically traced back to 1832 AD when Thomas 


\end{document}
```

The authors appear as: 
[image]

I wish it would be `Author One^1, Author Two^2, Author Three^1,2, and Author Four^3`.  Why `Authsep{, }` and `Authands{, and }` commands do not work?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I am not getting the output you mention under the `article` document class. So you must be doing something different. Could you supply the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: No. We don't need an entire `bibliography` since it has nothing to do with the problem. Keep it *minimal*. Click the link I provided to see what is meant by a MWE. Remove all the unnecessary stuff while still being able to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Werner -Excellent suggestion! I found out the problem: it is due to the `\begin{multicols}{1}` and `\end{multicols}`.  After removing them, the authors are separated as expected.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from `Werner`, I figured out the problem: it is due to the `\begin{multicols}{1}` and `\end{multicols}` that are flanking the `author` and `affiliation` portion.  Removing `multicols` fixed the problem (see the correct result in the photo).

[image]